# ¿Cómo instalar pyhook desde el ide de pycharm?

Tags: python

tengo un problema al intentar instalar pyhook en pycharm, tengo el siguiente error, alguien de casualidad sabe cómo podría arreglarlo. Dejo el mensaje de error

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyHook (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyHook

Comment: PyHook es en la práctica un proyecto obsoleto y sin mantenimiento , última versión en 2008 y en realidad solo para Python 2.x, aunque se podía hacer funcionar en Python 3. Hay un fork actualizado y mantenido que puedes probar [pyWinhook](https://pypi.org/project/pyWinhook/) o usar bibliotecas alternativas  como [pyautogui](https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoGUI/) también bien mantenida.

Comment: entiendo, muchas gracias